# Исключения в C

Tags: c, c++

Возможно ли в C добавить обработку исключений наподобие механизма C++?

```
try
{
}
catch
{
}
```

Если да, то каким образом?

Comment: [**`http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/`**][1]

[1]: http://code.google.com/p/exceptions4c/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Исключения в C реализуются с помощью пары [setjmp/longjmp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/yz2ez4as.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

Не знаю как делают обработку исключений Ъ-программисты, я же делал метки безусловного перехода(goto) и использовал стандартный заголовочный файл errno.h

Answer (score -1):

Возможно стоит посмотреть **signal.h**

Answer (score -2):

Язык C не поддерживает исключения, которые мы видим в C++, хотя бы только потому что исключения в C++ - это объекты, а как мы знаем объектов не бывает в C

Comment: Ну-у, не совсем. [GObject](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GObject), [KObject](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kobject.txt) — вполне себе объекты.

Comment: Минуснул, это неправильный некробамп. [Например](http://www.acm.uiuc.edu/sigops/roll_your_own/i386/idt.html).